# jquery help with layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, jquery-masonry

Hello I have following HTML,

```
    <article id="jobwall">
    <ul>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box noRMar">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
        <li class="box">Hello World</li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

And the following CSS,

```
#jobwall { 
        width:100%;
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
    }   

    #jobwall li {
        width:221px;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 17px 20px 0px;
        border:1px solid red;

    }

        #jobwall li.noRMar {
            margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;
        }
```

I am trying to implement a plugin for jquery called Masonary, the Idea is that I can fit 4 li's floated next to each other, however when I add masonary I can only float 3, here is my masonary setup,

$('#jobwall ul').masonry({

```
          singleMode: false,
          // Disables measuring the width of each floated element.
          // Set to true if floated elements have the same width.
          // default: false

          columnWidth: 241,
          // Width in pixels of 1 column of your grid.
          // default: outer width of the first floated element.

          itemSelector: '.box:visible',
          // Additional selector to specify which elements inside
          // the wrapping element will be rearranged.
          // Required for Infinite Scroll with window resizing.

          resizeable: true,
          // Binds a Masonry call to window resizes 
          // so layout appears fluid.
          // default: true

          animate: true,
          // Animates layout rearrangements.
          // default: false

          saveOptions: true
          // Masonry will use the options from previous Masonry
          // calls by default, so you only have to enter in options once
          // default: true

        });
```

basically I implementing masonary as the li with eventually show further content which will slide down, and I need the li's to continue floating in the order they are. Is there a better way to implement this, or have masonary allow for 4 li to be in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 4 * 221px (+ margins) greater than 100% width on the page?

Comment: You may need to make the last element in your list have no right margin as well.